Why do I need to CLR CMOS everytime I start/restart my PC with secure boot enabled?
I know there are other questions like this here and I have gone through all of them. It feels like my case is unique.
So, I have this problem when I have secure boot enabled. I need to CLR CMOS for it to boot because without that the PC is stuck on BIOS screen with the VGA LED turned on on my motherboard. The only way to fix it is to use the CLR CMOS on my motherboard after which the PC works fine and secure boot is still enabled. It only disables Platform Trust Technology [TPM] and X.M.P which I can enable without any problems by entering bios. And the same thing happens after every boot. The only way it'd let me in my bios or boot properly is if I use CLR CMOS and I don't get it because clearing cmos doesn't disable secure boot for me and YES when I disable secure boot, I can boot and reboot as many times I want and it doesn't get stuck on the bios screen.
Just to clear, this wasn't always the case. The PC is almost 7 years old and this has only been happening for a few months now.
My specs : ​

AORUS Z370 Ultra gaming 2.0 [Bios version F15 which is the latest for
my mobo]
Intel i5-8600K
Nvidia GTX 1060 6 GB
Deepcool 450W PSU
2 x 16 GB Corsair Vengeance @ 3000 MHz
XPG 1 TB NVME SSD

Things that I have already tried/checked :

Replaced CMOS battery.

Confirmed that my BIOS is set to UEFI and my SSD is GPT.

Reseated GPU and updated drivers [Also did a clean install with DDU].

Tried all variations to rule out RAM [single channel in each slot for
both sticks].

Reflashed BIOS.

Replaced PSU.

Tried running my PC without the APU.

Switching from Standard to custom in Secure boot.

Restoring keys/Reset to setup in secure boot.


I need secure boot and TPM enabled for Valorant.

Does your motherboard have a backup or secondary firmware? Is this behavior new? [Edit] your question instead of submitting commentary.

It has dual bios. I don't know anything about that feature.
Sorry ;-;
Also, the behavior started a few months ago and my PC is almost 7 years old

Since you have two a primary and secondary BIOS.  Have you hit the button to switch between them? I am going to ask you questions you might have to research to answer.  I will need answers to those questions in order to help

From what I read online, you can't switch back and forth between the two. The backup bios is a fail safe for when the original bios fails or gets corrupted, the backup bios flashes onto the main bios.
